# Selenium unable to find username and password field

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to log into a website by passing in username and password. I am using the following code (Python 3.5):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
url2 = 'https://services.yesenergy.com/PS/TimeSeriesAnalysis.html#d=a&title=Time Series Analysis'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url2)
username = driver.find_element_by_id("Username")
```

But I get the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"Username"}
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

Edit: I already tried the wait method to ensure the page is properly loaded but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instincts to check for page load are great, however, please look carefully at the html element you are trying to select:

```
<input placeholder="Username" type="text" name="j_username">
```

Notice that it does not have an `id` attribute, therefore you need to use another selection method.

An easy way to troubleshoot these kinds of problems interactively is to learn about using Chrome (or other browser) [web dev tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/edit-dom), [jQuery selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) and [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). Then you can choose the appropriate selenium method (`find_element_by_css_selector`).

For example, open up your browser's dev tools and paste this into the console:

```
$('input[name="j_username"]')
```

You will see that the correct element is selected. Now try using a method like this:

```
find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="j_username"]')
```

Comment: Can you please give a code snippet for clicking the "sign in" as there is no name for the button in the html page source.

Comment: If you spend a few minutes reading the CSS selector link it'll pay off in a huge way. If you get stumped after that I'm happy to guide you more.